# jQuery Find First Row From Closest Method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, I'm trying to find the first row of a given column in a table based on the control that has focus. The below kind of works, but it finds the last row of the given column. I want it to find the first row.

```
var $next= $('input:focus').closest('table').find('td:nth-child(3)').find('input')
```

I believe this is going to the last row because of the use of the 'closest()' method which traverses through the elements starting from the bottom.

What this ultimately being used for is navigate through a table using the arrow keys.  It's based on this helpful code someone was kind enough to share: https://gist.github.com/krcourville/7309218.

EDIT:  Adding additional fuller jquery and html as requested.

jQuery (stripped down version):

```
<script>
$('table.arrow-nav').keydown(function(e){
    switch(e.which){
        case //... other cases for other keycodes ...
        case e.ctrlKey && 38: // <ctrl> + <Up>
            $next = $('input:focus').closest('tr').parent().find("tr:first").find('td:nth-child(3)').find('input');
            break;
    }
    if($next && $next.length){
        $next.focus();
    }
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <table class="arrow-nav" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="ctl_1_1" type="text"></td>
        <td><input id="ctl_2_1" type="text"></td>
        <td><input id="ctl_3_1" type="text"></td>
        <td><input id="ctl_4_1" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="ctl_1_2" type="text"></td>
        <td><input id="ctl_2_2" type="text"></td>
        <td><input id="ctl_3_2" type="text"></td>
        <td><input id="ctl_4_2" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="ctl_1_3" type="text"></td>
        <td><input id="ctl_2_3" type="text"></td>
        <td><input id="ctl_3_3" type="text"></td>
        <td><input id="ctl_4_3" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the html that you are working with?

Comment: What do you mean by *I'm trying to find the first row of a given column...*? Rows might be said to have cells/columns but not vice versa! Stating clearly what you mean would be helpful.

Comment: As requested. I've added more html.  Also, to respond to PeterKA, another way of stating it is I'm looking for the first cell within a given column. Using my example added above, let's say "ctl_3_3" has the focus (I'm in row 3 column 3 ignoring the headers). I want to be able to find the cell that contains "ctrl_3_1". The first cell/row in a given column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$('input:focus').closest('tr').parent().find("tr:nth-child(2)").find('td:nth-child(3)').find('input')
```

Comment: Thanks. That didn't work for me.  I'll add my fuller html in response to other comments.

Comment: Ah ha! looking at your edited answer I now see why what I was trying wasn't working. I was finding the first "tr" or row, BUT... my first row was a header row with "th" in them and no "td".  So, it wasn't finding the cell I was looking for in that row (plus that row doesn't have any ctrls).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ids for referencing each row:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').on('focus', function(event) {
    var foc = $(this).attr('id');
    var ctl = parseInt(foc.charAt(6), 10);
    var next = $('tr')[ctl];
    if (next === $('tr')[2]) {
      next = $('tr')[0];
    }
    console.log('Focused input is ' + foc);
    console.log('The next row is ' + (ctl + 1));
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Next Row</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="arrow-nav" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="ctl_1_1" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="ctl_2_1" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="ctl_3_1" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="ctl_4_1" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="ctl_1_2" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="ctl_2_2" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="ctl_3_2" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="ctl_4_2" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="ctl_1_3" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="ctl_2_3" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="ctl_3_3" type="text">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="ctl_4_3" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```